# Add an active class to show active CPT taxonomy/category

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

How can I add an "active" class to this php snippet so I can highlight the active category?

add_shortcode('kb-cats-list', function(){

```
ob_start();

?>
<div class="kb-cat-list-wrapper"> 
<?php 
$cats = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'learn_category', 'hide_empty' => false, ) );
foreach($cats as $cat) { 
?>
  <div class="kb-cat-list">
    <div class="kb-cat-list-inner">
        <div class="kb-cat-title"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
<?php 
} 
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use WordPress default function `get_queried_object()` in order to check what the actual queried object is. If it matches `$cat` (ID or slug or whatever attribute) in your `foreach` loop, you add the "active" class for marking the element.